# Using XPath 2.0 to select nodes and keep hierarchical structure of source XML document

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

Is it possible to use **pure** XPath 2.0 expression to select nodes and keep hierarchical structure of source XML document?

An example source XML instance document:

```
<persons>
      <person name='Joe' age='26'>
            <project name='dom4j' language='java'/>
            <project name='underscore' language='javascript'/>
            <project name='ember' language='javascript'/>
      </person>
      <person name='Jane' age='23'>
            <project name='dom4j' language='java'/>
      </person>
      <person name='Kevin' age='15'>
            <project name='myMMORPG' language='php'/>
            <project name='struts2' language='java'/>
      </person>
</persons>
```

So I want to get a result of a pure XPath expression like:

```
<persons>
    <person name='Joe' age='26'>
        <project name='dom4j' language='java'/>
    </person>
    <person name='Jane' age='23'>
        <project name='dom4j' language='java'/>
    </person>
</persons>
```

This is easily to do with XSLT, but I'm curios, if it is at all possible to achieve this with a **pure** XPath 2.0 expression. I believe not, as I know there is no expression in XPath itself that creates new nodes. Can someone confirm this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for your question "Is it possible to use pure XPath 2.0 expression to select nodes and keep hierarchical structure of source XML document?", I would answer that as yes, the selection you do with XPath 2.0 returns nodes in the original input document, with the complete structure not being changed, meaning a selected node keeps it children, ancestors and siblings. Your wanted result, however, does seem to want to preserve only children and ancestors, but not siblings. To achieve that, you indeed need XSLT or XQuery and return new document with only the nodes you are interested in.

Comment: So in this example there is no XPath expression which can return the wanted result.

Comment: Yes, there is no XPath expressions that can return the wanted result from the input you have posted.